# Microsoft Store. How do I get all prices for all markets with C# code?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps

I need to get all prices for all markets.

Is it possible to get different prices for different markets (countries), and not just the base price for the add-on?

This code always returns only the base price:

```
var context = StoreContext.GetDefault();
var productKinds = new[]
{
    "Application", "Game", "Consumable", "UnmanagedConsumable", "Durable"
};

var associatedProducts = await context.GetAssociatedStoreProductsAsync(productKinds);
var storeProducts = associatedProducts.Products.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);

var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var (_, product) in storeProducts)
{
    var skus = product.Skus.ToArray();

    sb.AppendLine($"{++counter:D2}. {nameof(StoreProduct)}. StoreId: {product.StoreId}, InAppOfferToken: {product.InAppOfferToken}, " +
                    $"ProductKind: {product.ProductKind}, Language: {product.Language}, Title: {product.Title}, Skus.Length = {skus.Length}.");
    sb.AppendLine("StoreSku:");

    StoreSku storeSku = skus.FirstOrDefault();
    if (storeSku != null)
    {
        var availabilities = storeSku.Availabilities?.ToArray() ?? new StoreAvailability[0];
        foreach (StoreAvailability item in availabilities)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($"    {nameof(StoreAvailability)}. StoreId: {item.StoreId}, Price.CurrencyCode: {item.Price.CurrencyCode}, Price.FormattedPrice: {item.Price.FormattedPrice}.");
        }
    }

    sb.AppendLine();
}

string log = sb.ToString();
Debug.WriteLine(log);
```

`https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/products/{STORE_ID}/submissions/{SUBMISSION_ID}/availability`

[image: https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/products/{STORE_ID}/submissions/{SUBMISSION_ID}/availability]

Comment: The [FormattedPrice property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storeprice.formattedprice?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Services_Store_StorePrice_FormattedPrice) represents the purchase price for the product with the appropriate formatting for the market of the current user.

Comment: Have tried to get the products in different markets?

Comment: I don't know how to do this. Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: Just change the market of your account and try to run the code again.